# Disable on-click modal opening?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to stop the modal from opening on a page like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/tawxao2x/

As you can see from the snippet that it's just dragging the code in from a different source..

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="olapic_specific_widget"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="https://photorankstatics-a.akamaihd.net/81b03e40475846d5883661ff57b34ece/static/frontend/latest/build.min.js"  data-olapic="olapic_specific_widget" data-instance="61009ce94d8298d23e8b0481ac23bf20" data-apikey="f7f217fadcb8dad0bab9395c689114b74d48dbb84aa6fba32c1aa71c0a95f5e1" async="async"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Is there a piece of JS that I can add to disable the modals? I've searched on google but no luck.

Comment: i bet you actually didn't google because first thing that came up is what you need: [remove attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp).

Comment: are you trying to avoid an ad? that's not very nice if you are using a free service to host your website

Comment: @woncker 1. It's not a free service & their name is still present.
2. I want to remove it because it's going on a monitor, which will be placed on a wall (portrait) and the modal comes up too high to press the exit button.